# Error while added djangorestframework-gis in view.py

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm trying to create an API using bbox and I'm writing the function as per official doc of

```
class LocationList(GenericAPIView):
    queryset = Transaction.objects.all()
    serializer_class = LocationSerializer
    bbox_filter_field = 'point'
    filter_backends = (InBBoxFilter,)
    bbox_filter_include_overlapping = True # Optional
```

I have imported InBBoxFilter as follows

```
from rest_framework_gis.filters import InBBoxFilter
```

but I'm getting the following error

```
 File "/src/api/transaction/views.py", line 11, in <module>
    from rest_framework_gis.filters import InBBoxFilter
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework_gis/filters.py", line 9, in <module>
    from rest_framework.filters import BaseFilterBackend
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/filters.py", line 11, in <module>
    from django.db.models.sql.constants import ORDER_PATTERN
ImportError: cannot import name 'ORDER_PATTERN' from 'django.db.models.sql.constants' (/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/constants.py)
```

I tried following this https://www.gitmemory.com/issue/encode/django-rest-framework/7470/670721109 (using djangorestframework==3.11.1) but didn't work

Comment: Try upgrading rest framework? That constant was removed in Django 3.1

Comment: tried `pip install djangorestframework -U` but still not able to resolve

Comment: What error do you get? Make sure you are using the correct pip, I find a lot of issues with which pip is being used can be solved by using  `python -m pip` instead of `pip`